# How to get rotational speed after disk-disk collision with friction?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, friction, collision

Assume two circular disks A and B collide. They have both initial linear momentum and angular momentum. If their surface has no friction, their angular velocity does not change after collision, so I can easily calculate their final linear and angular momentum.

But what if their surface has some friction? In that case, their angular velocity will change after collision, and I can't guess how they will change.

If the friction coefficient $\mu$ is given, can I calculate their final linear and angular momentum?

Comment: "If their surface has no friction, their angular velocity does not change after collision" - so we are assuming 2D, right?

Comment: yes. I'm considering only 2D collision.

Comment: This is a reasonable problem that leads to the treatment of frictional forces as impulses. See http://ruina.tam.cornell.edu/research/topics/collision_mechanics/new_algebraic_rigid_body.pdf

Comment: Other relevant work as it relates to simulations (and game development) found here https://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs468-03-winter/Papers/ibsrb.pdf

Comment: We need more details about the collision.  How do the directions of the linear momenta compare? How do the directions of the angular momenta compare? By 2D, do you mean that the perpendicular axes of the disks are aligned and their faces collide? Are the axes collinear?  Without these details, the general answer is tremendously complicated.  Bottom line: both linear and angular momentum will be conserved (ignoring gravitational effects). System mechanical energy conservation will depend on friction.

Answer (score 3):

Considering both the discs as the system , we can conserve angular momentum about their collinear axis of rotation .
The torque due to friction will decrease the angular velocity of the disc having more angular momentum (before the collision ) while the torque will increase angular velocity of the one which had lesser initial angular momentum .
I am assuming the most general case in which you might have got stuck up since you havent given enough information